# XSLT: Group different element types

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, grouping, muenchian-grouping

My source XML looks as follows:

```
<A>
  <item>
    <X>10</X>
    <Y>20</Y>
    <Data1>Foo</Data1>
  </item>
</A>
<B>
  <item>
    <X>10</X>
    <Y>20</Y>
    <Data2>Bar</Data2>
  </item>
</B>
<A>
  <item>
    <X>11</X>
    <Y>20</Y>
    <Data1>Foo2</Data1>
  </item>
</A>
<B>
  <item>
    <X>11</X>
    <Y>20</Y>
    <Data2>Bar2</Data2>
  </item>
</B>
```

Note that `A`s and `B`s always occur pairwise with respect to the values of `X` and `Y`. Note also that there are also other elements containing a nested `item` element which should be ignored. Now, my goal is to group the elements having the same values for `X` and `Y` into new elements looking like this:

```
<NewElement>
    <X>10</X>
    <Y>20</Y>
    <Data1>Foo</Data1>
    <Data2>Bar</Data2>
</NewElement>
<NewElement>
    <X>11</X>
    <Y>20</Y>
    <Data1>Foo2</Data1>
    <Data2>Bar2</Data2>
</NewElement>
```

I have read about Muenchian grouping, but it seems that this only works for the same elements (e.g., in my example I could group all `A`s having the same values for `X`and `Y`). How can I group different elements?

Comment: If (?) I understand your description correctly, this is not really about grouping. It seems you only need to create a `NewElement` for each `A` and populate it with data from both the current `A` and the corresponding `B`.

Comment: I think you are right - stupid me. I will post my solution (which is probably slightly easier to understand) and accept that one - hope you are happy with the "answer is useful" credits...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Michael was right - no need to perform grouping for my problem. Here's the solution I ended up using, which is probably not as elegant as the one posted by him, but maybe a bit easier to understand:

```
<xsl:template match="A/item">
  <NewElement>
    <X><xsl:value-of select="X"/></X>
    <Y><xsl:value-of select="Y"/></Y>
    <Data1><xsl:value-of select="Data1"/></Data1>
    <Data2>
      <xsl:variable name="localX" select="X"/>
      <xsl:variable name="localY" select="Y"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="../../B/item[X = $localX and Y = $localY]/Data2"/>
    </Data2>
  </NewElement>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="b" match="B/item" use="concat(X, '|', Y)" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="A/item">
            <NewElement>
                <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="key('b', concat(X, '|', Y))/Data2"/>
            </NewElement>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

applied to your input example (after adding a `root` element to make it well-formed!), produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <NewElement>
      <X>10</X>
      <Y>20</Y>
      <Data1>Foo</Data1>
      <Data2>Bar</Data2>
   </NewElement>
   <NewElement>
      <X>11</X>
      <Y>20</Y>
      <Data1>Foo2</Data1>
      <Data2>Bar2</Data2>
   </NewElement>
</root>
```